# C: pointer references incorrect value

Tags: c, arduino

I need to send a value saved in a variable. When trying to pass this in my payload it keeps referencing to the initial value of mydata, which is unsuccessful test.

```
    static uint8_t *mydatapnt;
    uint8_t *strdata = "Successfull test";
    static uint8_t mydata [] = "Incorrect test";   

    void send(){
      if (LMIC.opmode & OP_TXRXPEND) {
      Serial.println(F("OP_TXRXPEND, not sending"));
      } else {
         // Prepare upstream data transmission at the next possible time.
         LMIC_setTxData2(1, mydata, sizeof(mydata)-1, 0);
         Serial.println(F("Packet queued"));
    /
    }

    void setup(){
     *mydata = mydatapnt;
    }

    void loop(){
     *mydatapnt = strdata;
     Serial.println(*mydatapnt + "");
    }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I should receive "successfull test".
You can find the full code project [here](https://gist.github.com/themaawaa/5d857a53b155c7903296255c6be94626)

Comment: First, enable warnings. Second, `*mydata = mydatapnt;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Where is `strdata` used?

Comment: `*mydatapnt = strdata;` is undefined behavior (as `mydatapnt` is not initialized and even if it was that is not how you copy strings)

Comment: @Lundin *mydatapnt should be *mtdatapnt = strdata. Fixed that.

Comment: `*mydatapnt + ""` does not concatenate. You really have to read about strings.

Comment: All your uses of `mydatapnt` are errors. If you aren't seeing error messages from your compiler then the very first thing to do is change compiler settings or whatever so you you do see the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About strings...

Strings are just pieces of memory where characters are stored (an array of characters). Strings are terminated by a null character.

To copy a string, you must have sufficient memory in the target string. Then you use `strcpy` to copy the characters. `strcpy` appends the terminating null character.

The size of a string is determined with `strlen`. It does not count the terminating null charcter.

In

```
char *strptr = "my string";
```

the pointer points to the literal string. A literal string is read-only. Trying to modify it often leads to a segmentation fault or other terminal error. In:

```
char myString[] = "my string";
```

The characters of `"my string"` are *copied* to the array `myString` and the compiler makes its size of the length of the initializing string, plus a null character.

To append to a string, you use `strcat`. Again, the target must have sufficient memory. You either declare a char array with enough memory, like `char mystr[100];` or you can allocate memory with `malloc`, for example:

```
char *strptr= malloc(strlen(myString)+1);
strcpy(strptr, myString);
```

If you no longer need the memory you got from `malloc`, you must return it to the memory allocator:

```
free(strptr);
```

Trying to use `strptr` after having freed the memory will also result in a segmentation fault or in some other undefined behavior.

Comment: Maarten, the hints are clear enough that you can find that out yourself. There are many possibilities; you have to choose one. Try it, and come back if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

> `*mydatapnt = "success in loop";`

This does not store pointer to `"success in loop"` string into `mydatapnt`, but rather store address of that string into first character of `mydatapnt`. (At this time `mydatapnt` is not initialized, so it clobbered some random memory location.)

What you more likely wanted to do is: `mydatapnt = "success in loop";`

> `Serial.println(*mydatapnt + "");`

You're not concatenating strings, but adding value of first char from `mydatapnt` to pointer to empty string, which is more like substring operation. This will likely print *something*, because of the way strings are stored in executable, but definetely not what you wanted it to print.

You can't concatenate strings in C with simple `+`. Try just `Serial.println(mydatapnt)`.